# Change background color of each terminal window individually

Tags: terminal, ubuntu-18.04

I am working with multiple terminal windows and I'd like to change them so I can keep them straight.  The preferences for the terminal application change the background color of all terminal windows.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be about programming, so it would be better asked in the StackExchange [Unix/Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) sites.  Anyway, one way to do it is to create multiple "profiles" in the terminal's Preferences dialogue, specify a different background colour (and/or theme) in each profile, and then apply a different profile to each terminal window (and/or tab).

Comment: OK.  Thanks.  Feel free to close or delete the question

Answer (score 0):

you can use xfce4-terminal, when configured you can automatically have a new color for each new terminal